# For $\mathbb{X}$ with order relation and field structure extended from $\mathbb{R}$, if it includes real line, then is it real line?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, logic

For a set $\mathbb{X}$ given order relation and field structure extended from those of $\mathbb{R}$, if $\mathbb{X} \supseteq \mathbb{R}$ then $\mathbb{X} = \mathbb{R}$ ?

This question is derived from [the previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731624).

Comment: This question is answered in my answer to the previous one. Both the rational functions and the non-standard models of analysis are ordered fields that extend the field structure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Eg. $\mathbb R(x)$, the fraction field of the ring of polynomials with real coefficients $\mathbb R[x]$ clearly contains $\mathbb R$ as a proper subfield.